# trying to use copy(JSON.stringify(result))

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am using the console in my browser to scraper and sort content using JS.
Here is my code

This is my result array

```
var arr = [
"George\nPresident & Founder",

"content",

 "Ronald\nCountry Director, America",

 "content",

 "Kriss, PhD\nVice President",

 "content",

 "Joseph, MS\nDirector",

 "content",

 "Elizabeth\nDevelopment Operations",

 "content",

 "Lisa, MFA, MBA\nU.S. Content",

 "content.",

 "Natalia\nCountry Director"
]
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
  for(var i=0; len = result.length, i < len; i++){
    result[i]['something'] = [];
    if(i === 0){
        result[i].split('\n');
    }
    else if (i % 2 === 0) {
        result[i].split('\n');
    }
    console.log(result[i]);
    result[i]['test'].push(result[i]);

  }
```

This comes back as result[i]['something'] = []; is undefined
but when i console.log(result[i]) i get the right result. Ive tried to copy(JSON.stringify(result[i])) but I only get back one object.

```
for(var i=0; len = result.length, i < len; i++){
    var arr = [];
    if(i === 0){
        result[i].split('\n');
    }
    else if (i % 2 === 0) {
        result[i].split('\n')
    }
    arr.push(result[i])
    // console.log(result[i]);
    console.log(arr);
  }
```

This doesnt split them, it just pushes them into the arrays.

When I console.log(result[i]) I get:
(this is right but its not in strings nor is it in arrays; I also cant copy this either)

```
George
President & Founder

 content 

  Ronald
  Country Director America 

  content 

  Kriss PhD
  Vice President 

  content 

  Joseph MS
  Director 

  content 

  Elizabeth
  Development Operations 

  content 

  Lisa MFA MBA
  U.S. Content 

  content

  Natalia
  Country Director
```

My end goal should look like this:

```
var result = [
["George"],
["President & Founder"],

[ "content" ],

[ "Ronald"]
["Country Director, America" ],

[ "content" ],

[ "Kriss, PhD"],
["Vice President" ],

[ "content" ],

[ "Joseph, MS"],
["Director" ],

[ "content" ],

[ "Elizabeth"],
["Development Operations" ],

[ "content" ],

[ "Lisa, MFA, MBA"],
["U.S. Content" ],

[ "content." ],

[ "Natalia"],
["Country Director" ],
[ "content." ]
]
```

What can I do so that I get the result[i] and copy it onto my clipboard using copy(JSON.stringify(result))?

Comment: There are many issues in what you have tried. Why is the input an array of arrays and not just an array of strings? Why would you give an array a `'test'` property? `split` is not modifying anything -- it returns a result, but you ignore it. Too many problems... and then you ask about copying and clipboard. This is too broad. You should probably step back and start with something simpler and first check that it works before extending it.

Comment: the result array was actually suppose to be an array of strings. Sorry about that.  As for 'test', if thats a naming convention issue, i can change it, but i dont understand how that has anything to do with problems in the code...

Comment: You would give a `'test'` property to a plain object, but not to an array -- or after the input is corrected to an array of string -- not to a string (which is primitive). If you feel this has nothing to do with problems in the code, then I fear you are wrong. But you should anyway provide the minimal code to reproduce the issue of your question, so if you believe that `'test'` property has nothing to do with it, it should not be in your question.

Comment: ok i just changed the name 'test' to 'something' so that should fix that issue

Comment: The problem is not with the name, the problem is that you assign to a property of something that is not an object. A string primitive has no space to store properties. They will go into oblivion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers seem intriguing. I will suggest a slightly longer one which has a few for loops.

This is what I came up with:

**UPDATED:** I've updated it to work now that you have updated your post as well.

```
function changeArr(array) {
    // create a temporary array
    let tempArr = [];
    
    // loop through the array which was passed as an argument
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let splitArr = array[i].split("\n");

        // splitArr returns an array containing the 2 strings which have been split

        // using the spread operator from ES6 we can spread out the elements and push them into tempArr
        tempArr.push(...splitArr);
    }
    
    // tempArr should now contain your end result
    return tempArr;
}
```

**How to use:**

```
changeArr(arr);

/*
this will return:

=> [
    "George",
    "President & Founder",

    "content",

    "Ronald",
    "Country Director, America",

    "content",

    "Kriss, PhD",
    "Vice President",

    "content",

    "Joseph, MS",
    "Director",

    "content",

    "Elizabeth",
    "Development Operations",

    "content",

    "Lisa, MFA, MBA",
    "U.S. Content",

    "content",

    "Natalia",
    "Country Director",

    "content"
]
```

With this, you can either make another variable called `let result` and store whatever the function returns in it.

```
let result = changeArr(arr);
```

**Or** you can assign whatever the function returns to the `arr` variable.

```
arr = changeArr(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would generate an array of objects.  Since you have two rows in the array per person (except for Natalia, she has no content?), you can loop through the array jumping two at a time gathering the info for each person into an object.

```js
var arr = [
"George\nPresident & Founder",

"content",

 "Ronald\nCountry Director, America",

 "content",

 "Kriss, PhD\nVice President",

 "content",

 "Joseph, MS\nDirector",

 "content",

 "Elizabeth\nDevelopment Operations",

 "content",

 "Lisa, MFA, MBA\nU.S. Content",

 "content.",

 "Natalia\nCountry Director"
];

const result = [];
for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i+=2) {
  const nameParts = arr[i].split("\n");
  result.push({
    name: nameParts[0],
    title: nameParts[1],
    content: arr[i + 1]
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This answer was extremely helpful. This is actually the actual output I wanted, with the labels like in your answer. I just simplified my question because I wasnt able to get through the split(\n) part but the fact that you killed multiple birds with one stone is insane. so thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

remove  arr.push(result[i]) and try this

```
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
      arr.push( result[i].split('\n'));
    }
else
{
   arr.push(["content"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive your goal by using `reduce` method much more easier like this:

```js
let arr = [
  "George\nPresident & Founder",
  "content",
  "Ronald\nCountry Director, America",
  "content",
  "Kriss, PhD\nVice President",
  "content",
  "Joseph, MS\nDirector",
  "content",
  "Elizabeth\nDevelopment Operations",
  "content",
  "Lisa, MFA, MBA\nU.S. Content",
  "content.",
  "Natalia\nCountry Director"
]
let result = arr.reduce((acc, str) => {
  str.split('\n').forEach(str => acc.push([str]));
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This doesn't use the same data sample for `arr`

Comment: @wahwahwah Yes, I implemented my answer by previous version and I didn't see the updated version of data. I edited my answer. thanks.